# How can I trigger an action in a user control from another control (eg a button)

Tags: wpf

I would like to run a method in my user control when a button is pressed. What is the best way of achieving this? I don't want to go via code behind.

My example looks like this:

```
<Button Content="Do something in MyUserControl" Width="200" Height="100" Click="{Here I want to trigger an action in MYUserControl}"/>

<local:MyUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Should I have an eventhandler in MyUserCOntrol? Or a command? Or a dependency property?
This seems like it should be easy but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: If you dont want to do it through code behind then use `Command`, for that you will need a ViewModel behind the host and `UserControl`.

Comment: I know i could do it via a command in the the view model. 
I want to go straight from the button to the user control.
I think what I'm after is how to expose methods in a user control that can be triggered by events in other controls such as buttons.

Comment: Bigger question is why User Control has a behaviour? All of that should be in VM.

Comment: hmm maybe you're right.

Comment: Use the same viewmodel for all